# Not receiving all telegram notifications from telegram client api

Tags: java, tcp, callback, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using the telegram client API to receive updates. I have a callback to handle the response types, I tested it by listening for updates from a channel I created myself, the updates came through flawlessly. I also had a friend create a channel and the same happened.

However, when a large channel (pretty much most of them) broadcast a message, I'm not receiving the update? I've reset all notification settings so they're not disabled but it still fails to send me an update. In fact, I've found sometimes I get the updateShort thrown when large channels message. Is there a chance Telegram doesn't think the large channels are important and fails to update me?

Edit: Specifically, how does telegram decide on what updates to send me? (Thank you below for telling me  the question isn't clear)

Comment: Where is the programming question in this? What is your code and do you think there is a problem with it?

Comment: Question is the last sentence. It's not the code, more to do with how telegram decides on what updates to notify you with. I receive updates from all notifications in small groups, just not large. I'm wondering why, or to be specific, do they ignore large groups and see them as unimportant?

Wrapper is Kotlogram

Comment: @AaronWhite I'm having the same issue as you, have you found any explanation or solution for this?

Comment: Did you find the solution? @AaronWhite